# Quel est la différence entre « couper » et « découper » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Quel est la différence entre les deux ? « Couper » est fait avec le couteau et « découper » est fait avec des ciseaux ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Couper* : diviser (*ou* enlever quelque chose qui tient à un ensemble) (*ou encore* prendre, former [un morceau]) avec un instrument tranchant.
>
> *Diviser* un morceau, en coupant ou détachant au bon endroit [une pièce de viande qu'on sert à table par exemple], (*ou* couper régulièrement en suivant un contour,  un tracé) (*ou encore* détacher avec des ciseaux un contour, une figurine).

Dans *couper* l'action est de 'trancher' pour détacher un morceau (on peut couper avec des ciseaux une carte à puce en deux) la précision, l'endroit où se fait la coupe n'est pas significatif.

Dans *découper*, l'action de trancher ou de séparer n'est acceptée que s'il y a un but à atteindre, quels que soient les instruments utilisés.

<sup>*Références extraites du petit Robert*</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Vous pouvez éventuellement couper quelque chose sans qu'il reste un autre morceau (séparé) : se couper le doigt, par exemple. Dans le cas de découper, il doit au moins rester un autre morceau (comme pour : découper la viande).

Comment: Pour le doigt, vous utilisez le verbe *se couper* dont le résultat est une *coupure*, une petite coupe occasionnant une *blessure* ; il n'en reste pas moins que la peau, à cette endroit est séparée ; la censure faite aussi des *coupures* dans les œuvres intellectuelles. *Couper* donne une *coupe* quand il y a séparation totale, et *découper* fait une *découpe*, ou un *découpage* ; *découpure* est rare il représente l'action comme le résultat du verbe découper.

Answer (score 1):

**Couper est le plus simple , le plus utilisé**, a donné lieu à de multiples expressions, et est plus axé sur l'acte lui même plus que sur le résultat, **et peut s'employer presque comme synonyme de découper**:

> Couper de la viande, couper une feuille, couper un fruit, couper du bois.

**Pronominal:**

> se couper = se taillader.

**expressions, plusieurs sur le sens de *stopper*, *interrompre*:**

> couper court, ne pas y couper, couper la parole, couper quelqu'un, couper les cheveux en quatre , se couper, couper (tailler) dans le gras, couper des crédits, couper le robinet.

Il donne le substantif *coupe*, qui est l'action, et *coupure*, qui est l'**emplacement** qui a été coupé.

**Découper est moins employé, plus restreint**, a un sens vraiment concret, et résulte **en des morceaux**:

> découper la viande, découper un fruit, découper des feuilles, ...

Il donne le substantif découpage, qui est **l'action globale.**

Il a quelques emplois techniques: découpage au cinéma.

**On peut couper ou découper avec des ciseaux ou un couteau.**

Answer (score 0):

Couper est une action courte. Découper est une action longue.
On coupe un fruit. Le boucher découpe de la viande.
On coupe une feuille en deux, on découpe un bonhomme dans une feuille.