# "Dé"couper, le mauvais élève du préfixe "dé"

Tags: sens, histoire, préfixes

Je me permets de poser une question pour laquelle je n'ai jusqu'ici reçu aucune réponse satisfaisante dans mon insignifiante existence.

*Le préfixe -dé a un rôle bien précis en français :*

*Wiki :*

> dé- \de\
>   Préfixe
>   Donne à un mot, le plus souvent un verbe, le sens opposé, s'opposant souvent au préfixe en- (em-), parfois a(c)- ou in-.
>   accord → désaccord, bloquer → débloquer, infecter → désinfecter, installer → désinstaller, entartrer → détartrer, etc.
>   Forme un verbe indiquant qu’on enlève qc ou qu’on prive de qc..
>   panne → dépanner, courage → décourager, etc.

*Pour les verbes, je rajouterai :*

> décoller / déconnecter / défaire / dégobiller ...

**Alors, pourquoi, découper et couper ont-ils un sens similaire ?**

Cela ne m'empêche plus de dormir, mais le savoir résolu me ferait beaucoup de bien.

Edit : [Je connais cet article qui répond à la question "quoi"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14011/quel-est-la-diff%C3%A9rence-entre-couper-et-d%C3%A9couper), mais la question ici est bien le **pourquoi** ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tout d'abord, il y a le troisième [rôle](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%C3%A9-) du préfixe *dé-*, soit de *renforcer le sens d’un verbe*. C'est dans cette catégorie qu'on classe [*découper*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9couper) au *TLFi* :

> Préfixe issu de la particule latine *de-*, qui en composition, pouvait
>   donner au mot simple une valeur perfective marquant l'intensité (ex.
>   *miror* → *demiror*), et qui en français indique le renforcement d'une action (valeur augmentative, intensive) dans les verbes qu'elle sert
>   principalement à former.

Puis on spécifie « couper en morceaux » pour *découper* par opposition à *couper*. On note que ce rôle est davantage vivace par emprunt au latin que par composition directement en français. Pour une description plus détaillée des autres rôles de l'élément formant *dé-* (l'éloignement, la privation, la cessation, la négation, la destruction de qqc., l'action ou l'état contraire, inverse), voir l'[entrée](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9-/2) au *TLFi*.

Answer (score 3):

Je ne réponds pas vraiment à la question mais le postulat sur lequel elle s'appuie n'est pas avéré. **Couper**/**découper** n'est pas le seul exemple de ce type, il existe quelques autres groupes de verbes plus ou moins similaires dont au moins :

- **nier**/**dénier**
- **plumer**/**déplumer**
- **poser**/**déposer**
- **périr**/**dépérir**
- **rober** (Vx)/**dérober**
- **tenir**/**détenir**
- **tonner**/**détoner**

Comment: Cela ne répond peut-être pas mais en agrandissant la famille, ce n'est plus la même question, ni peut-être même une question légitime ! Merci ☺

Answer (score 1):

[selon cet article](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%C3%A9-#fr) on trouve le sens suivant :

Forme un verbe indiquant qu’on enlève qc ou qu’on prive de qc..
panne → dépanner, courage → décourager, etc.

Mon hypothèse est donc, étant donné le sens de découper (rappel : action de couper mais avec un but à atteindre), que découper représenterait l'action de couper pour séparer, donc amputer quelque chose d'une partie d'elle-même. On aurait donc la nuance pour montrer que cette partie n'est pas juste détériorée, mais enlevée.

Dis-moi si je ne suis pas clair !

Comment: Haha ! J'apprécie l'effort de réflexion, en effet, je vois l'idée de la différence d'origine, même si au final, il tend à penser qu'à travers l'action de **découper** il reste quelque chose au final, alors qu'en **coupant**, *on peut tout perdre*. Le sens de la gravité est donc inversé, et "**dé**"couper n'est pas juste une accentuation de couper. Nous avançons, mais nous ne répondons toujours pas au **pourquoi**.

Answer (score 0):

Tu peux trouver une reponse ici:  [Voila](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14011/quel-est-la-diff%C3%A9rence-entre-couper-et-d%C3%A9couper)

D’après cet article:

**Découper :** On découpe le papier avec des ciseaux et la viande avec un couteau en plusieurs morceaux.

**Couper :** On coupe les cheveux, un fil, une branche d'arbre, le gazon, le courant (électricité), etc.

Couper = Une seule fois ou un seul morceau.

Découper = Ça veut dire quelque chose comme séparer.

J’espère que ça puisse t'aider :)

Comment: Je connais les définitions et les subtilités, mais la question n'est hélas pas là ! Il n'existe pas, à ma connaissance, d'autres verbes avec le préfixe "dé" qui possède un sens aussi similaire, et non contraire, à son original. Et la question reste donc, **pourquoi ?**

Comment: Si, il en existe d'autres…

Comment: Oui effectivement, ta réponse est bien complète ! Merci