# Que signifie « retenus » dans cette phrase?

Tags: grammaire, sens, philosophie

> Le terme cause et le terme effet sont l'un et l'autre élaborés par l'esprit, définis exactement, et les caractères retenus pour la définition proviennent d'une abstraction conceptuelle qui découpe les éléments, sans tenir compte toujours de la solidarité réelle des institutions.

J'ai plusieurs questions sur cette phrase.Tout d'abord, quel est le sens de « terme » ? Ensuite, que signifie « retenus » dans cette phrase? Enfin, est-ce que le verbe *découper* » signifie *couper* ?
Merci d'avance.

Comment: Un terme c'est un mot ou ensemble de mots ayant, une signification précise et exprimant une idée définie. [TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/terme). Mot est un synonyme acceptable dans cette phrase. « Retenus » ici veut dire « pris en compte », « acceptés ». [Quel est la différence entre « couper » et « découper » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/14011/358).

Comment: couper: Imaginez: vous avez un ruban, vous le coupez en deux avec des ciseaux, par exemple. Maintenant, imaginez une morceau de papier (pour la couture), vous découpez un patron à partir du papier. **découper implique une surface** (comme le papier) de laquelle vous enlevez une partie en utilisant un outil coupant.  Il y a même une technique artistique qui s'appelle le découpage. Des formes (en papier ou métal) comme des feuilles, par exemple, sont "extraits" d'une surface de paper ou métal (ou même le bois) utilisant des ciseaux.

Comment: Dans votre texte, l'action coupante est effectué par l'abstraction conceptuelle.

Comment: Avec des *termes* (mots) choisis, le *patron* (d'entreprise) *met un terme* (arrête) la réunion et *retiens* (garde dans la salle et laisse les autres sortir) les ouvri·ers·ères qui *ont retenu* (se souviennent de) l'utilisation du *patron* (du *modèle* [ou de la *forme* {mot qui a de nombreux emplois différents} dans d'autres métiers]) en papier pour la *découpe* (coupe [nom] selon un tracé précis) du tissu.

Answer (score 4):

Les caractères qui ont été *retenus* sont les caractères qui ont été gardés après examen d'un ensemble de caractères dont  certains ont probablement été éliminés.  C'est le verbe *retenir*.

Exemple en situation :
Le gouvernement lance un appel à projet pour distribuer des aides aux entreprises. Un comité se réunit pour examiner tous les 200 projets qui sont arrivés. Le comité en *retient* 10 (qui l'intéressent probablement en fonction de la somme disponible), 10 projets *ont été retenus*, 190 ont été refusés.